# Istio Load balancing to multiple namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have two namespaces hosting different versions of my services, namespace *sh-blue* hosts one version of each service and *sh-green* hosts new version of each service. With each new deploy all services are updated to new version. I want to implement canary deployment from current version to new version.

The code below is what I currently have and it's working fine, except it's not obvious what kind of load balancing it is using. When I check *ingress-gateway* logs it's something like: blue, green, green, blue, green, green, green, red, green, blue, blue, blue, green, green, ...

Is it possible to control the load balancing? And is there a better way to setup this?

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: sh-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*.something.local"
```

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: sh
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - sh-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /index
    route:
    - destination:
        host: index.sh-blue.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8080
      weight: 50
    - destination:
        host: index.sh-green.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8080
      weight: 50
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /config
    route:
    - destination:
        host: config.sh-blue.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8080
      weight: 50
    - destination:
        host: config.sh-green.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8080
      weight: 50
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem as you. Did you find a better way to control the load balancing in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify load balancing configuration within Istio `DestinationRule` traffic management [resource](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#DestinationRule) . It requires `trafficPolicy` to be included for the mesh service in order to control load balancing [policy](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#TrafficPolicy).

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-ratings-port
spec:
  host: ratings.prod.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy: # Apply to all ports
    portLevelSettings:
    - port:
        number: 80
      loadBalancer:
        simple: LEAST_CONN
    - port:
        number: 9080
      loadBalancer:
        simple: ROUND_ROBIN
```

For more information I do suggest to visit Istio Load Balancer settings [overview](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#LoadBalancerSettings).

Comment: In my example virtual service is 50/50 routing between two different services, `DestinationRule` is applied after one of the services is chosen. If I set `ROUND_ROBIN` it happens only when load balancing pods inside one of the services.I would like to be able to set how requests are balanced between the two services, at the moment it looks random.

Comment: I would create a two separate `VirtualService` for `prefix: /index` and `prefix: /config` paths respectively bounded to the same `Gateway` and look at the traffic distribution then, just to check the behavior.